# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input', how to fix in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have imported `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` file.

can anyone tell me where i did mistake ?

**Error**
[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

....

imports: [
   ....
    FormsModule,
   ....
 ]
```

**about.component.html**

```
<form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="banner">Banner Image Url</label>
                <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    [(ngModel)]="banner.banner_image"
                    id="banner"
                    name="banner"
                />
            </div>
        </form>
```

**about.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import {UserService} from '../../service/user.service';

class Banner {
  id: number;
  banner_image: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    banner: Banner = new Banner();

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

}
```

Comment: Is the AboutComponent declared in the app.module.ts?

Comment: @Jesse yes it's declared in app.module.ts file

Comment: I could be wrong but I _think_ you don't use the banana-in-a-box syntax [()] when you are inside of a <form>... Sorry, I wish I could be more help. I mostly use Reactive Forms.

Comment: Make sure that `FormsModule` is imported under the decorative of `NgModule`.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had problems like this where the build doesn’t pick up a new import. Maybe try re compiling?

Comment: This was my next thought. I've run into this as well.

Comment: @Jesse i imported wrongly. Actually i my project i have two component with name `About`. that's why i was facing this error

Comment: Ahhh, I've done that before. Nice work hunting that down.

Comment: @Don G as i got to know after re-compile, where was the issue, i can accept your answer but can you also mention the reason also what i shared in my above comment?

Comment: Just in my experience I’ve seen lots of times where i imported a new package or component and something wasn’t acting right. All of my code was perfectly fine. Shutting down and re-building the entire project fixes it, usually. Kinda like a “turn it off and back on”. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Import ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

If this **About** component is a part of some nested module, then include **FormsModule** in nested module file.

Including it in app.module.ts will not work.